# Lightning Event not passing attributes to the handler

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning event

prodEvent

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template">
    <aura:attribute name="productMap" type="Map" />  
</aura:event>
```

Here is the component where the event is registerd

**ChildComponent**

```
<aura:attribute name="productMap" type="Map" />
<aura:registerEvent name="getAllProductsMap" type="c:zAOBAddRemoveProductsgetProductsEvent" />
```

**helper function firing the event**

```
fireGetProductsEvent: function(component,event) {
        var prodMap = component.get("v.productMap");
        var prodEvent = $A.get("e.c:zAOBAddRemoveProductsgetProductsEvent");
        prodEvent.setParams({
            "productMap" : prodMap
        });
        prodEvent.fire();
    }
```

**Parentcomponent handling the event**

```
<aura:handler event="c:zAOBAddRemoveProductsgetProductsEvent" action="{!c.getAllProductsMap}" />
```

**helperfunction in parentcomponent**

```
getAllProductsMap: function(component, event){
    console.log('zproductPickerCompHelper.getAllProductsMap');
    var evt = $A.get('e.c:zAOBAddRemoveProductsgetProductsEvent');
    var prodmap = evt.getParam("productMap"); // undefined
    debugger;
    component.set("v.productMap", prodmap); 
    console.log('zproductPickerCompHelper.getAllProductsMap');
}
```

I am receiving an undefined value in prodMap. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the method you are catching the event you dont have to declare an event of your own. You can just use the one passed as a parameter .

```
 getAllProductsMap: function(component, event){
        console.log('zproductPickerCompHelper.getAllProductsMap');

        var prodmap = event.getParam("productMap"); // This will have your values
        debugger;
        component.set("v.productMap", prodmap); 
        console.log('zproductPickerCompHelper.getAllProductsMap');
    }
```